# How to evaluate fields using text/template package? go

Tags: templates, go

I have a template and I would like to evaluate various fields using the [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package. I have a hard to time to figure it out how the evaluation should work because the code below seems to fail. Is the template package powerful enough to handle this kind of evaluations?

```
type something struct{
    Brand   string
}
tpl := `{{if .Brand == "Coke"}} It's a coke{{else}} It's something else{{end}}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a global function in the templates package named `eq` that you can call. Not sure why it works like that but here is the code

```
type something struct{
    Brand   string
}
tpl := `{{if eq .Brand "Coke"}} It's a coke{{else}} It's something else{{end}}`
```